# How can I stream in a Vercel Serverless function? It's working in local, but not once deployed

Tags: node.js, artificial-intelligence, serverless, vercel, chatgpt-api

I'm testing some ChatGPT functionalities, and found out how to stream the responses as if they were typed in real-time.

While I'm able to reproduce this correctly in my local, for some reason when I deploy this, the response only shows once the full message is loaded.

Vercel [documentation](https://vercel.com/docs/frameworks/nextjs#streaming:%7E:text=Vercel%20supports%20streaming%20for%20Serverless%20Functions%2C%20Edge%20Functions%2C%20and%20React%20Server%20Components%20in%20Next.js%20projects.) states this:

> Vercel supports streaming for Serverless Functions, Edge Functions, and React Server Components in Next.js projects.

I've only been able to find documentation about how to do it to [stream for Edge Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/edge-functions/streaming), not for Serverless.

Here you can compare how it works for local, but not for deploy:
[image]

This is the repo: https://github.com/andna/errorsrepo
with this being the specific handler:

```js
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");

const configuration = new Configuration({
    apiKey: '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',
    //this key was deleted after video recording
    //replace with your own free API KEY obtained here: https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

export default async function handler(req, res) {

    try {
        const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
            stream: true,
            messages: [
                { role: "system", content: "You are an AI." },
                { role: "user", content: "how are you?" }],
        }, { responseType: 'stream' });

        completion.data.on('data', data => {
            const lines = data.toString().split('\n').filter(line => line.trim() !== '');

            res.write("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>");

            for (const line of lines) {
                const message = line.replace(/^data: /, '');
                if (message === '[DONE]') {
                    res.end();
                    return; // Stream finished
                }
                try {
                    const parsed = JSON.parse(message);
                    const content = parsed.choices[0].delta.content;
                    if(content){
                        res.write(content);
                    }
                    ;
                } catch(error) {
                    console.error('Could not JSON parse stream message', message, error);
                }
            }


        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred during OpenAI request', error);
    }



}
```

Any help how to make it work in prod too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @AcclaimHosting, there are many differences.

Ended up following this example with Edge Functions instead of serverless:
https://vercel.com/blog/gpt-3-app-next-js-vercel-edge-functions#the-frontend

Answer (score -2):

I understood your problem I have found a 99% true solution related to this at vercel community. I am sharing the link with you and you you can go there and check out the answer.

[Vercel Solution Link](https://vercel.com/guides/why-does-my-serverless-function-work-locally-but-not-when-deployed)

Thank You! Have A Great Day!